# What's type FI and UNKNOWN in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop

I'm new to OCaml. I installed utop(version 2.6.0) with latest homebrew on MacOS, installed libraries with `opam install core base`.

Here's my `.ocamlinit`:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "core.top";;

open Base;;
open Core;;
```

I met an error of type `FI`:

```
utop # FI;;
Line 1, characters 0-2:
Error: The constructor FI expects 3 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 0 argument(s)
```

What's type `FI` in OCaml ?

Here's type `info` introduced in TAPL([https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/tapl/)): `type info = FI of string * int * int | UNKNOWN`,

What's type `UNKNOWN` in OCaml ?

Comment: `info` is a variant type with two possible values - `FI` or `UNKNOWN`. Consult an ocaml tutorial or the manual for more.

Answer (score 0):

As all the commenters are telling you, StackOverflow is not a good place to learn a new language by asking questions. It will be much, much more productive for you to start by reading through a tutorial on OCaml, say at [the OCaml Learning page.](https://ocaml.org/learn/)

To answer your questions here, neither of these identifiers (`FI` or `UNKNOWN`) means anything in particular "in OCaml". They're just upper-case identifiers that can be defined to be many possible things. In your case they are defined by the type definition you cite:

```
type info = FI of string * int * int | UNKNOWN
```

This defines the names `info`, `FI`, and `UNKNOWN`. The latter two are the "constants" of a new type named `info`. The first constant (called a value constructor actually), `FI`, is a way of collecting up a string and two ints into a unit with the tag `FI`. The second one is just a simple value that doesn't collect up any data. It's similar in a way to `NULL` in some other language, in that it says there is no interesting data.